# Doc to PDF - delete copied file but not when Doc is in root

Tags: google-apps-script

Code below works when doc is in a folder but not when it is in drive root.
Then PDF is deleted. How can I make this work when doc is in root?

```
function saveToPDF(){
var currentDocument = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFileById(currentDocument.getId()).getParents();
var folderId = parentFolder.next().getId();
var currentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);

var pdf = currentDocument.getAs('application/PDF');
pdf.setName(currentDocument.getName() + ".pdf");

var file = DriveApp.createFile(pdf);
currentFolder.addFile(file);
DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(file);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If doc is in root folder in your code this will add the file to the root drive:

```
currentFolder.addFile(file);
```

Then this line in your code removes the file you just created:

```
DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(file);
```

So to avoid this use a check to see if doc is in root folder:

```
var rootFolderID = DriveApp.getRootFolder().getId();
```

and compare with

```
var folderId = parentFolder.next().getId();
```

Something like:

```
if (folderId != rootFolderID)
  {DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(file);
}
```

Comment: I am fairly new to google script and didn't now about the '!=" code yet. Now I do know. And I thought I needed something with an if..then structure. Thank you, I learned something today!

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted